# Appropriate clause with 'if'

Tags: conditional-constructions

Which one should I use?

1. If you could solve this problem, I'll give you a chocolate.
2. If you solved this problem, I'll give you a chocolate.

Comment: For both (1) and (2), "I'd (I would) give you a chocolate". (3) "If you will solve this problem, I'll (I will) give you a chocolate."

Comment: In each case, if you use a past tense verb like "could" or "solved" in the subordinate clause, you should also use a past tense modal verb like "would" in the matrix clause. 2. for example, should  be (_If you **solved** this problem, I **would** give you a chocolate_). Contrast this with _If you **solve** this problem, I **will** give you a chocolate_.

Comment: @KateBunting (3) "If you will solve this problem, I'll give you a chocolate" -- I'm wondering does this statement guarantees that the problem is 'solved'? Cause 'solve' also suggests act, like when we say "solve/try this problem"

Comment: It assumes that the person being addressed will be able to solve the problem, if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

Neither is correct. Either of these would work:

- If you can solve this problem, I'll give you a chocolate.
- If you solve this problem, I'll give you a chocolate.